# Как заменить символ в подстроке по конкретному индексу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задумался над тем,можно ли заменить подстроку в строке по конкретному индексу. Есть str.replace(old,new,n). Но он заменяет начиная слева то количество подстрок n, что задано.
Написал такой код:

```
while True:
    if start_index != None and last_index == None:
        print(f"Замена в строке -{str_for_replacement}- элемента {value_from_replace} на {value_to_replace}")
        str_for_replacement =str_for_replacement[0:start_index]+str_for_replacement[start_index:].replace(value_from_replace,value_to_replace,1)
        print_str_result = input(f"Сейчас строка выглядит так {str_for_replacement}. Хотите продолжить заменять {value_from_replace} в строке?").lower()
        if print_str_result == 'yes' or print_str_result == 'y' or print_str_result == 'да':
            print("Продолжаю удаление.")
        else:
            break


    if last_index!=None and start_index == None:
        print(f"Замена в строке -{str_for_replacement}- элемента {value_from_replace} на {value_to_replace}")
        str_for_replacement =str_for_replacement[0:last_index].replace(value_from_replace,value_to_replace,1)+str_for_replacement[last_index:]
        print_str_result = input(f"Сейчас строка выглядит так {str_for_replacement}. Хотите продолжить заменять {value_from_replace} в строке?").lower()
        if print_str_result == 'yes' or print_str_result == 'y' or print_str_result == 'да':
            print("Продолжаю удаление.")
        else:
            break


    if start_index != None and last_index!=None:
        print(f"Замена в строке -{str_for_replacement}- элемента {value_from_replace} на {value_to_replace}")
        str_for_replacement =str_for_replacement[0:start_index]+ str_for_replacement[start_index:last_index].replace(value_from_replace,value_to_replace,1) +str_for_replacement[last_index:]
        print_str_result = input(f"Сейчас строка выглядит так {str_for_replacement}. Хотите продолжить заменять {value_from_replace} в строке?").lower()
        if print_str_result == 'yes' or print_str_result == 'y' or print_str_result == 'да':
            print("Продолжаю удаление.")
        else:
            break

return str_for_replacement
```

Но уверен что можно иначе. Кто-то знает?

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '''
    Есть какой-то текст, в котором мы хотим просмотреть
    наличие подстроки (например: `текст`) и при необходимости заменить этот текст на `1234567`.
    Данный текст будем просматривать построчно.
    Я не совсем уверен, что понял ваши задачу.
'''

_from = 'текст' 
_to   = '*ТЕКСТ*'   
_fromLen = len(_from)
new_text = [] 

for line in text.splitlines(): #split("\n"):
    n = line.count(_from)  
    if n:
        for i in range(n):
            print(f"\n{line}")
            ix = line.find(_from)
            print(f"{' '*ix}{_from}")
            yes = input("Хотите заменять? нажмите `что-нибудь`+Enter \nНажмите Enter, замены не будет!: ")
            if yes:
                print(f"Yes")
                line = line[:ix] + _to + line[ix+_fromLen:]
            else:
                print(f"No")
        new_text.append(line)
    else: new_text.append(line)

print("\nВот обновленный текст:")
print( "\n".join(new_text ))
print("\nВот старый текст:")
print(text)
print('-'*80)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы делать замены таким образом, чтобы еще указывать какое включение шаблона изменять, можно с помощью самых базовых инструментов накидать следующую функцию, где `t`- текст, `template`- шаблон замены, `value` - значение замены, `n` - индекс/номер шаблона в тексте

```
def replace_template_by_inclusion_number(t, template, value, n):
    tt = t.split(template)
    t_new = []
    line = range(1, len(tt) + 1)
    for i, ti in zip(line, tt):
        t_new.append(ti)
        if i != line[-1]:
            t_new.append('{}#@#{}'.format(template, i))
    t_new[t_new.index('{}#@#{}'.format(template, n))] = value
    t_result = [x.split('#@#')[0] if '#@#' in x else x for x in t_new]
    return ''.join(t_result)

print replace_template_by_inclusion_number("asdf a a a a a asdf b b b b asdf", "asdf", "qwerty", 2)
print replace_template_by_inclusion_number("asdf a a a a a asdf b b b b asdf", "asdf", "qwerty", 3)
# asdf a a a a a qwerty b b b b asdf
# asdf a a a a a asdf b b b b qwerty
```